# Error installing uwsgi with pip: "Python.h no such file". python-dev and python3-dev packages are installed

Tags: python, pip, uwsgi

I'm getting the following error when trying to install uwsgi using pip on ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo pip3 install uwsgi
...
    plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
```

I have installed the `python-dev` and `python3-dev` packages. Running `locate Python.h` shows that it is indeed installed:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
```

I've tried installing using both `pip` and `pip3`, and I get the same error. Every other answer to this question points to having `python-dev` or `python3-dev` or some variant installed, and I've tried all those. Any ideas what else might cause this?

Comment: Do you only have 2.7 and 3.6 installed or possibly also another python 3x ?

Comment: Add the output of `sudo python3-config --cflags` and the build log of `sudo pip3 install uwsgi -vvv --no-cache-dir` (starting from `Running setup.py install for uwsgi` till the end).

Answer (score 34):

This is exactly the same problem I've faced today after I upgraded from `3.6` to `3.7`.

Solve this problem by installing `libpython3.7-dev`:
`sudo apt install libpython3.7-dev` / `libpython3.*-dev` which version you use.

then install `uwsgi` again :
`pip install uwsgi`

the output should look like:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uwsgi ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/user/.cache/pip/wheels/2d/0c/b0/f3ba1bbce35c3766c9dac8c3d15d5431cac57e7a8c4111c268
Successfully built uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi, weasyprint
Successfully installed uwsgi-2.0.18 weasyprint-50
```

Hope this help.

Comment: `sudo apt install libpython3-all-dev` package depending on all supported Python 3 development packages.

Comment: @iColdPlayer I can't thank you enough. Your solution was a life saver. It just worked.

Comment: Solved my problem, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, after installing `build-essential`. I used `libpython3.8-dev`. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

These two lines did the trick for me on Linux 8.2

```
yum install python3-devel
pip3 install uwsgi -vvv --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 1):

My python version is 3.6, I do this to solve my problem:

```
yum -y install python36-devel
```

Comment: what to do for python3.8 ? facing a similar issue while using rh-python38

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora, did

```
sudo dnf install python3-devel
pip install uwsgi
```

with success

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35143096)